# Await on a completed task same as task.Result?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm currently reading "*Concurrency in C# Cookbook*" by Stephen Cleary, and I noticed the following technique:

```
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTask, timeoutTask);  
if (completedTask == timeoutTask)  
  return null;  
return await downloadTask;
```

`downloadTask` is a call to `httpclient.GetStringAsync`, and `timeoutTask` is executing `Task.Delay`.

In the event that it didn't timeout, then `downloadTask` is already completed. Why is necessary to do a second await instead of returning `downloadTask.Result`, given that the task is already completed?

Comment: I'm not seeing an actual check for successful completion here. The task could very well be faulted, and in that case the behaviour *will* be different (`AggregateException` with `Result` vs first exception via `ExceptionDispatchInfo` with `await`). Discussed in more detail in Stephen Toub's "Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx)

Comment: you should make this an answer @KirillShlenskiy

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You're right, thanks for noticing, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

There are already some good answers/comments here, but just to chime in...

There are two reasons why I prefer `await` over `Result` (or `Wait`). The first is that the error handling is different; `await` does not wrap the exception in an `AggregateException`. Ideally, asynchronous code should never have to deal with `AggregateException` at all, unless it specifically *wants* to.

The second reason is a little more subtle. As I describe on my blog (and in the book), [`Result`/`Wait` can cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), and [can cause even more subtle deadlocks when used in an `async` method](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). So, when I'm reading through code and I see a `Result` or `Wait`, that's an immediate warning flag. The `Result`/`Wait` is only correct if you're *absolutely sure* that the task is already completed. Not only is this hard to see at a glance (in real-world code), but it's also more brittle to code changes.

That's not to say that `Result`/`Wait` should *never* be used. I follow these guidelines in my own code:

1. Asynchronous code in an application can only use `await`.
2. Asynchronous utility code (in a library) can occasionally use `Result`/`Wait` if the code really calls for it. Such usage should probably have comments.
3. *Parallel* task code can use `Result` and `Wait`.

Note that (1) is by far the common case, hence my tendency to use `await` everywhere and treat the other cases as exceptions to the general rule.

Comment: We encountered the deadlock using 'result' instead of 'await' in our projects. the messed up part is having no compile error and your code becomes flaky after a while.

Comment: @Stephen would you please explain me why "Ideally, asynchronous code should never have to deal with AggregateException at all, unless it specifically wants to"

Comment: @vcRobe Because `await` prevents the `AggregateException` wrapper. `AggregateException` was designed for parallel programming, not asynchronous programming.

Comment: > "Wait is only correct if you're absolutely sure that the task is already completed."

....

Then why is it called Wait?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: The original purpose of `Wait` was to join to [Dynamic Task Parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663539.aspx) `Task` instances. Using it to wait for asynchronous `Task` instances is dangerous. Microsoft considered introducing a new "Promise" type, but chose to use the existing `Task` instead; the tradeoff of reusing the existing `Task` type for asynchronous tasks is that you do end up with several APIs that simply shouldn't be used in asynchronous code.

Comment: @StephenCleary when you say `Parallel task code can use Result and Wait`, what do you mean by that? Say I have two `Task`s and use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for them to finish. Should I use `await` to get the result? Or is `Result` acceptable?

Comment: @PatrickTucci: "Parallel task code" is using dynamic task parallelism, i.e., running tasks on thread pool threads and chaining them together. It has nothing to do with `async`/`await` or `WhenAll`. In your case, it sounds like you have asynchronous concurrency, so `await` is the proper tool.

Comment: 2PatrickTucci After having passed tasks to WhenAll I use Result instead of await, to me it's clearer code, since the task already have run, awaiting it again seems a bit wrong

Answer (score 13):

This makes sense if `timeoutTask` is a product of `Task.Delay`, which I believe what it is in the book.

`Task.WhenAny` returns `Task<Task>`, where the inner task is one of those you passed as arguments. It could be re-written like this:

```
Task<Task> anyTask = Task.WhenAny(downloadTask, timeoutTask);
await anyTask;
if (anyTask.Result == timeoutTask)  
  return null;  
return downloadTask.Result;
```

In either case, because `downloadTask` has already completed, there's a very minor difference between `return await downloadTask` and `return downloadTask.Result`. It's in that the latter will throw `AggregateException` which wraps any original exception, as pointed out by @KirillShlenskiy in the comments. The former would just re-throw the original exception.

In either case, wherever you handle exceptions, you should check for `AggregateException` and its inner exceptions anyway, to get to the cause of the error.