# Is there a difference between calling .Result or await on known completed tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Is there any functional, performance, or risk of deadlock difference in the below code blocks?

Example 1:

```
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); 
var result1 = await task1; 
var result2 = await task2;
```

Example 2:

```
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); 
var result1 = task1.Result;
var result2 = task2.Result;
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result

Comment: Result can cause deadlocks. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result

Comment: @Cody - In this case I believe it is impossible for it to deadlock as the task is already complete.

Comment: @JacodeGroot - Stephen Clearly's answer on that question is pretty detailed, thanks for the link. In this case Task.WhenAll() would've already unwrapped the AggregateException, so that's not a concern.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any functional, performance, or risk of deadlock difference in the below code blocks?

No, there isn't any such a case.

In both cases a task is created that will be completed when `task1` and `task2` would be completed.

Hence, when you write:

```
var result1 = await task1; 
var result2 = await task2;
```

the code will be executed synchronoulsy. You don't have to `await` for something, since you both `task1` and `task2` would have completed.

The same holds, for the second example, where you try to get their results.

```
var result1 = task1.Result;
var result2 = task2.Result;
```

Since, the tasks have already completed, you don't block any thread calling thread or having any context switch etc.

**Update**

The only functional difference that exists between these two approaches is that the error handling is different. The `await` just unwraps an `AggregateException`, while `.Result` will just raise the exception.

Comment: There is a functional difference, error handling is different. `await` will unwrap a `AggregateException` where `.Result` will just raise the exception intact.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you for your comment. I will include it in my answer.