# C# HTTPClient Response Logging

Tags: c#, json, ssis, httpclient

I have the below code which I am using to send JSON data to an API using HTTPClient. I want to log the HTTP response/status code such as 200, 201, 400 etc. Please can someone assist me with how to log the response code?

```
Current code:

      public void Main()
        {
            //String filePath = @"your-path\test.json";
            String filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read the JSON file
                    string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://your-url.com");
                        var response = client.PostAsync("/url-path", new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
                        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error reading or parsing the JSON file: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The JSON file does not exist in the specified folder.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);` prolly you need to cast to integer since this is enum ... but ... where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostAsync method returns a [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=net-7.0) which conatains [IsSuccessStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpresponsemessage-issuccessstatuscode) and the [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpresponsemessage-statuscode) property.
If you use them your code will be like this :

```
public void Main()
{
    //String filePath = @"your-path\test.json";
    String filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
    if (File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        try
        {
            // Read the JSON file
            string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://your-url.com");
                var response = client.PostAsync("/url-path", new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());

                    var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error reading or parsing the JSON file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The JSON file does not exist in the specified folder.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient.PostAsync` method returns `HttpResponseMessage` object, which contains `StatusCode` property and other additional info about response.

So, you can simply get it after execution as "StatusCode (StatusCodeDescription)" by using this string example: `$"{(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.ReasonPhrase})"` (outputs like `200 (OK)`, `500 (InternalServerError)` etc):

```
public void Main()
{
    // ...
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // ...
        var response = client.PostAsync(...).Result;
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.ReasonPhrase})"); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

**BUT**, execution of request may also throw an `HttpRequestException` (on timeout, as simplest example). And, in case you declare both `HttpClient` and `HttpResponseMessage` inside `try`-block - you can't get `response` info in a `catch`-block. That's why you should declare it out of `try-catch` blocks:

```
public void Main()
{
    // ...
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = (HttpResponseMessage?)null;
    // ...
    try
    {
        // ...
        response = client.PostAsync(...).Result;
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.ReasonPhrase})");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here you have access to response object, but don't forget null-checks
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int?)response?.StatusCode} ({response?.ReasonPhrase})");
    }
}
```

Also, should be mentioned lots of stuff about code, like:

- don't declare `HttpClient` inside method to avoid overhead (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client));
- don't use `.Result` on awaitable `Task`s to avoid deadlocks (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213842/deadlock-when-using-result));
- don't forget to `await` your `Task`s. Line from your code `responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` will store `Task<string>` object inside `responseContent` variable, not pure `string` as you may expect. And you should `await` this call to get string.

Assuming that, I recommend you to declare and initialize `HttpClient` only once, somewhere out of methods, and reuse it. Also mark your methods as `async` to be able to await `HttpClient` calls. In that way you get proper request calls, response handling and ability to log response. Simple example:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new() { BaseAddress = new Uri("SomeBaseUri") };

public static async Task Main()
{
    // ...
    var response = (HttpResponseMessage?)null;
    var responseContent = string.Empty;
    // ...
    try
    {
        // ...
        response = await _client.PostAsync(...);
        responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine($"Request executed with status: {(int)response.StatusCode} ({response.ReasonPhrase}). " +
                          $"Response body: {responseContent}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with status: {(int?)response?.StatusCode} ({response?.ReasonPhrase}). " + 
                          $"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }

    // If job with HttpClient done - don't forget to dispose it manually:
    _client.Dispose();
}
```