# In regards to Task<T>, is there a difference between Await and Task<T>.Result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

In the Task Parallel Library, or the TPL in .NET, when using asynchronous operations, there seems to be two ways to await the completion of the task:

If you have this...

```
Task<int> intReturningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IntReturningFunc() );
```

You can await it with this...

```
int x = await intReturningTask;
```

but I believe you can also await it like this...

```
int y = intReturningTask.Result;
```

My question is is there a difference between the two? My guess is 'no' and that `await` exists for the non-generic version of Task which doesn't have a result, but that's just speculation.

Comment: `.Result` isn't `await`ing, it is blocking. The non-generic `Task` has `Task.Wait()` which is the same as `.Result` but without a result.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result

Comment: You also never want to use .Result anyhow, but its twin GetAwaiter().GetResult() and even that extremely rarely.