# Exception When Deserializing an ISO Date in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, httpclient, datacontractjsonserializer

I am trying to deserialize an API response to a class object. But I get the error:

> DateTime content 2017-11-15T10: 00: 00 does not start with \ / Date (and not ending) \ /, which is required for JSON.

My Code:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APP_URL);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(APPLICATIONJSON));

DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<HttpConference>));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(GET_ALL_CONFERNECES).Result;

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

System.IO.Stream svar = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

List<HttpConference> model = (List<HttpConference>)serializer.ReadObject(svar);
```

In the database I am using `datetime`.

The Json response:

```
[
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Namn": "Conference Microsoft",
    "StartDatum": "2017-11-15T10:00:00",
    "SlutDatum": "2017-11-15T12:00:00",
    "KonferensID": null
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "Namn": "föreläsning",
    "StartDatum": null,
    "SlutDatum": null,
    "KonferensID": null
}
]
```

this is the errormessage thrown by the code:

> 'svar.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

I get an error at the ReadAsStreamAsync:

```
EDIT
```

> ReadTimeout = 'reply.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/17/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api/) article that talks about this problem. But I didn't know how to implement it in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see that JSON response

Comment: You should also think about using Json.Net for JSON handling, even MS is using it, guess why

Comment: update my question

Comment: How should I use `Json.Net for JSON handling` with my code

Comment: Well you can go to the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm#!) and read the Getting Started paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you agree to use JSON.NET here is a solution with it:

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t18YbX)

```
public static void Main()
{
    // I use the json direclty instead of the httpClient for the example
    var json = @"[
    {
    ""ID"": 1,
    ""Namn"": ""Conference Microsoft"",
    ""StartDatum"": ""2017-11-15T10:00:00"",
    ""SlutDatum"": ""2017-11-15T12:00:00"",
    ""KonferensID"": null
    },
    {
    ""ID"": 2,
    ""Namn"": ""föreläsning"",
    ""StartDatum"": null,
    ""SlutDatum"": null,
    ""KonferensID"": null
    }
    ]";

    // See the official doc there: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
    var conferences = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Conference>>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(conferences[0].StartDatum);
}

// this class was generated with http://json2csharp.com/
public class Conference
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Namn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDatum { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SlutDatum { get; set; }
    public object KonferensID { get; set; } // we cant know the type here. An int maybe?
}
```

Output

```
 11/15/2017 10:00:00 AM
```

Outside of the deserialization problem, you should use [async/await instead of Result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657079/1248177).

Comment: Cant get this to workk becasue I still get the error at the `ReadAsStreamAsync`, updated the question.

Comment: @AllramEst So you have a httpclient async problem not a json problem.