# ASP.Net Core Razor components: await vs .Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Consider the following two lines in View file for ASP.Net Core:

```
    @Component.InvokeAsync("Greeting").Result
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Greeting")
```

What is the difference? Which is preferable and in which situation? In my code they both give the same visual result; are there cases where results could be different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Await on a completed task same as task.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both calls most likely takes the same time to return, the difference is that the first call will block the thread but the second call will return the thread to the pool and allow it to be used by another request. Essentially meaning that your Service can handle more requests per second when using the `await` keyword.

Use `await` where possible to prevent the thread from blocking. Do some reading on async and await - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

From MSDN - The `await` keyword is where the magic happens. It yields control to the caller of the method that performed await, and it ultimately allows a UI to be responsive or a service to be elastic.

Essentially the `await` keyword yields control back to the caller and releases the thread back into the threadpool.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `.Result` will result in a blocking call which *could* cause issues with your UI. If you're calling an asynchronous function, you should `await` it to allow the rest of your application to continue without being blocked.

Answer (score 3):

**NB**: [Razor Components](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/10/03/blazor-update.aspx) are something different - this is **server-side hosted Blazor**, part of .NET Core 3.0. What you mean, however, is ASP.NET Core x.x [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 1):

Calling **.Result** on the component makes you lose the essence of the **await** which is suppose to prevent blocking your UI as the code does not need to wait for the complete execution of the Razor component.

Hence it is advisable not to call the **.Result** rather you should **await** the result to allow the complete asynchronous execution flow of your code.