# Xamarin Forms: IOS adhoc crashes but debug works

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, response

I have a very strange problem, I programmed an app that triggers a webservice and gives me a response back. This also works on android and IOS (in debug mode) but when I install the app via adhoc it still works but when I press the button that triggers the webservice the app freezes and you have to restart it but it always stops at the same place.

I have found out with a lot of commenting and commenting out that the error happens in the marked place. In debug mode everything works as it should.

Here is the code that will be executed.

```cs
IsMYSite(strLink);

if (gotResponse)
{
    gotResponse = false;
    DetailPage.MYPages.Add(new MYPage { Title = portal, Link = strLink, Username = "", Password = "", IsVisible = false, CompanyImage = ImageLink });
    App.Current.Properties["MYPages"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DetailPage.MYPages);

    App.Current.Properties["LastPortal"] = strLink;

    Navigation.PopAsync(true);

    LinkURL.TextColor = Color.Black;
}
else
{
    LinkURL.TextColor = Color.Red;
}

public async void IsMYSite(String url)
{
    try
    {
        String linkonly = url;
        url += "/api/" + CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName;
        string strpost = "";
        StringContent str = new StringContent(strpost, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));


        Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        portal = result["PortalTitle"];

        if (result["LoginLogo_Path"].StartsWith("~"))
        {
            StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder(result["LoginLogo_Path"]);
            str2.Remove(0, 1);
            ImageLink = linkonly + str2.ToString();
            gotResponse = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are deadlocking, use `await` instead of `.Result`, there are lots of SO Q/As concerning this, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657079/4984832 (this answer links to a couple of blog posts by Stephen Cleary....)

Comment: Thanks first of all but I changed the code to this : var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)); but this dont work because i get no response

Comment: Check the device log to see what is happening...also the default timeout is ~100 seconds, so are you actually timing out if you wait 2 minutes?

Comment: No it's happening directly. I added more code so you can see how my app is structured. Maybe its a logic bug because I'm new in this xamarin scene :)

Comment: Have you provided permissions of Internet in Android and iOS projects?

Comment: Yes I have all permissions but it won't work anyways :/

Comment: try changing async void to async Task and await it