# Task null using Task.Run and Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, xunit

I have two services that ultimately both update the same object, so we have a test to ensure that the writes to that object complete (Under the hood we have retry policies on each).

9 times out of 10, one or more of the theories will fail, with the `task.ShouldNotBeNull();` always being the assertion to fail. What am i getting wrong with the async code in this sample? Why would the task be null?

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    [InlineData(5)]
    [InlineData(10)]
    [InlineData(20)]
    public async Task ConcurrencyIssueTest(int iterations)
    {
        var orderResult = await _driver.PlaceOrder();

        var tasksA = new List<Task<ApiResponse<string>>>();
        var tasksB = new List<Task<ApiResponse<string>>>();

        await Task.Run(() => Parallel.For(1, iterations,
            x =>
            {
                tasksA.Add(_Api.TaskA(orderResult.OrderId));
                tasksB.Add(_Api.TaskB(orderResult.OrderId));
            }));

        //Check all tasks return successful           
        foreach (var task in tasksA)
        {
            task.ShouldNotBeNull();

            var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            result.ShouldNotBeNull();
            result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

         foreach (var task in tasksB)
        {
            task.ShouldNotBeNull();

            var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            result.ShouldNotBeNull();
            result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of awaiting a task that just blocks on a parallel for loop?

Comment: The `Parallel.For` is doing nothing for you here.

Comment: Thank you, so how should i improve it? Task.WaitAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for Tasks and Parrallel looping here. I'm presuming that your `_api` calls are IO bound? You want something more like this:

```
var tasksA = new List<Task<ApiResponse<string>>>();
var tasksB = new List<Task<ApiResponse<string>>>();

//fire off all the async tasks
foreach(var it in iterations){
   tasksA.Add(_Api.TaskA(orderResult.OrderId));
   tasksB.Add(_Api.TaskB(orderResult.OrderId));
}

//await the results
await Task.WhenAll(tasksA).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var task in tasksA)
{
    //no need to get GetAwaiter(), you've awaited above.
    task.Result;
} 

//to get the most out of the async only await them just before you need them
await Task.WhenAll(tasksB).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var task2 in tasksB)
{
     task2.Result;
}
```

this will fire all your api calls `async` then block while the results return. You Parallel for and tasks are just using additional thread pool threads to zero benefit.

If `_api` is CPU bound you could get benefit from `Task.Run` but I'm guessing these are web api or something. So the `Task.Run` is doing nothing but using an additional thread.

Comment: Thank you, that's roughly what i had first time i wrote the code, but a colleague suggested i use the Parallel.For.

Comment: It depends on if you process is CPU or IO bound. APIs are typically IO bound, when this is the case `Task`s add no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, remove the `Parallel`, and `await` on all tasks to finish before `asserting` them.

I would also recommend to remove `.Result` from each task, and `await` them instead.

```
public async Task ConcurrencyIssueTest(int iterations)
{
    var orderResult = await _driver.PlaceOrder();

    var taskA = _Api.TaskA(orderResult.OrderId);
    var taskB = _Api.TaskB(orderResult.OrderId);

    await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);

    var taskAResult = await taskA;

    taskAResult.ShouldNotBeNull();
    taskAResult.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var taskBResult = await taskB;

    taskBResult.ShouldNotBeNull();
    taskBResult.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: why await the tasks twice? `Task.WhenAll` will ensure that they've returned. The `await taskA` is essentially identical to `taskA.Result`

Comment: the await the second time is simply just getting the result from them. it is typically recommend over .Result() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result

Comment: *Recommended* is a bit strong. It's different. But the benefits are marginal. [*There are two reasons why I **prefer**.....*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657079/542251)