# PostAsync after execution immediately returns from where inherited

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, face-recognition

I'm trying to add a face to the faceset in Face++ API. But when I try to make an HTTP post request, it fails on PostAsync method. It just immediately returns to where it was inherited from. As in my example, after executing `var response = await client.PostAsync(addUrl, formData)`, it immediately returns to the Main method, giving me no response at all. Tried to `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, but it didn't help. Maybe you have some ideas why this is happening?

Documentation of the API: https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/40622182

API:

```
   public async Task<string> AddFace(string faceToken)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent keyContent = new StringContent(Keys.apiKey);
            HttpContent secretContent = new StringContent(Keys.apiSecret);
            HttpContent facesetTokenContent = new StringContent(facesetToken);
            HttpContent faceTokenContent = new StringContent(faceToken);

            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(keyContent, "api_key");
                formData.Add(secretContent, "api_secret");
                formData.Add(facesetTokenContent, "faceset_token");
                formData.Add(faceTokenContent, "face_tokens");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(addUrl, formData).ConfigureAwait(false);

                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                return responseString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

MAIN:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\dev\ProtingaVizija\SmartVision\d.jpg");
        FaceRecognition fr = new FaceRecognition();

        var face = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyzedFaces>(fr.AnalyzeImage(b));
        string faceToken = face.faces[0].face_token;

        Faceset fs = new Faceset("d8d6679e5b37c2612e420f94f0225159");
        fs.AddFace(faceToken);

        string x = fs.GetDetail().Result;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FormFaceDetection());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just edited the Main and it works!

```
string res = fs.AddFace(faceToken).Result;
```

Comment: That was [not the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657079/11683). You should have used `await`.