# How to wait for all tasks to be completed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that has two parts. need all the success of the first part before execute the second part.

Such as:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
var _taskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in someDataList)
{ 
    _taskList.Add(new Task(async () =>
    { 
        var result = await _req.ExecuteAsync(someParams).ConfigureAwait(false);
         _dic.TryAdd(result.data, result.data);
    }
}
_taskList.ForEach(t => t.Start());
await Task.WhenAll(_taskList.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (_dic.Count == List.count()
{
    //execute part 2.
}
```

not waiting for all tasks to be completed,
there is no data in the dictionary at any time.
and i try:

```
 while (true)
{
    foreach (var item in _taskList)
    {
       if (item.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
          goto continueWait;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work either.

Why is that? What should I do?

Comment: Your first for each loop looks wrongs it’s looping through what exactly?

Comment: *"there is no data in the dictionary"* - Where did you attempt to add data to the dictionary?

Comment: sorry,I updated the code

Comment: Debug the tasks. Arent they throwing exceptions?

Comment: Using `new Task()` is a very poor choice for an async operation as it basically uses up a thread to do work which a Task could avoid.  If this code ran on an IIS server, it may even prevent users from accessing the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be any data in your `dict` because passing in an `async` lambda is not going to make any difference in `Task`'s ctor.

You will need to restructure your code quite a bit. You want to call your `async` method, put the `Task` in your list and then `await` till of them complete. Once they're completed, then can you iterate over all your results in your task list and pull out the `.Result` from it.

```
var tasks = someDataList.Select(i => _req.ExecuteAsync(i) );
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var dict = tasks.ToDictionary(t=> t.Result);
if (dict.Count == List.count()
{
    //execute part 2.
}
```

Note that if `_dict` is a global variable and you need locking, then you should just replace `ToDictionary` with your `ConcurrentDictionary` code above as this is example code.

Comment: Just to expand on "an `async` lambda is not going to make any difference in `Task`'s ctor" - All the [constructors of `Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) take an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action), which is basically a `void` method. That means your anonymous function that you're giving it is interpreted as `async void`, which means that it cannot be awaited.

Comment: I would highly recommend against using `.Result` even here.  You can simply await the same task and get the result.  [Await on a completed task same as task.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result)

Answer (score 0):

The code below example of async loop

```
var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
    var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, bool>>>();
    foreach (var i in series)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Process {0}", i);
        tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(i));
    }
    foreach (var task in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
    {
        if (task.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", task.Item1);
        }
    }
```