# Custom header in HttpClient POST request not working

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I am trying to send a POST request when using HttpClient. When I run the code I am getting an unauthorized response. But I am able to get it to work in PostMan. Below is my current code snippet and  pictures of what I am trying to perform. I'd like to add I am trying to send a json string in my body.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var connectionUrl = "https://api.accusoft.com/prizmdoc/ViewingSession";
            var content = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "type", "upload" }, { "displayName", "testdoc" } };
            // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
            var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Acs-Api-Key", "aPsmKCmvkZHf9VakCmfHB8COmzRxXY5FDhj8F1FU1IGmQlOkfjiKESKxfm38lhey");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Acs-Api-Key", "aPsmKCmvkZHf9VakCmfHB8COmzRxXY5FDhj8F1FU1IGmQlOkfjiKESKxfm38lhey");

                // Do the actual request and await the response
                var httpResponse =  httpClient.PostAsync(connectionUrl, httpContent).Result;

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Do something with response. Example get content:
                    var connectionContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle a bad response
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: PostMan Header Segment]

[image: PostMan Body Segment]

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request headers  between the Postman results and the c# results.  One or more of the headers are different.  Then make c# application headers look exactly like the postman headers.

Comment: Could it be because your api-key's value is too short lived? i.e it expires very quickly

Comment: No, the api key is not randomly generated. It is used for all api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to haldo's answer,

In your code, you are adding your `Acs-Api-Key` header as and [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), meaning it ends up looking like `Authorization: Acs-Api-Key (key)` rather than `Acs-Api-Key: (key)` which is what you have in PostMan.

Instead of adding it as an Authorization header, just add it as a regular header.

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Acs-Api-Key","(key)");
```

Also something else that may cause issues is that you aren't wrapping your content in the "source" object like you are in PostMan. There are a couple ways of doing this

The first would be to simply wrap it in it's string format:

```cs
stringPayload = $"\"source\":{{{stringPayload}}}"
```

Or you can do it before you serialize by making your own object instead of having a Dictionary

```
var content = new PayloadObject(new Source("upload", "testdoc"));
var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

// Send the request

class PayloadObject{
    Source source {get; set;}
    PayloadObject(Source source){
        this.source = source;
    }
}
class Source{
    string type {get; set;}
    string displayName {get; set;}
    Source(string type, string displayName){
        this.type = type;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't totally sure which header to use in the code, as you can see I commented out what you suggested.

Comment: Yes I did notice that. I just wanted to clarify. The other problem is mentioned in @haldo's answer. *You're using two `HttpClient`s* where one has your header, and the other one doesn't. You are using the one without the header to send the request.

Comment: I fixed that as well. I think it may be about the source object. I am working on getting that right now to see if it works

Comment: After making all the changes, I now get a error "server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" after doing research into the error, I added a segment in web.config to useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true and it still doesn't work. Any idea what the problem here could be?

Answer (score 2):

You're using two `HttpClient`s when you only need to use one.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
```

and

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
```

The second one (`httpClient`) is doing the post but the authentication header has been added to `client`. Just remove the second one (`httpClient`) and make sure you use `client.PostAsync(...)` to send the request.

---

I'd also consider using `await`, rather than `.Result` (see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657079/9665021)) when sending the request:

```
var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(connectionUrl, httpContent);
```

Comment: I fixed the double httpclient(s) and still having a problem. I think it may be the source I am trying to send it. but thank you for pointing out the obvious double usage