# .Result or await after Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have two tasks, and I wait them to be finished with

`await Task.WhenAll`

Can it be a problem to get after that the value directly by calling `.Result`

I am sure that the tasks are already finished.

`

```
        Task<int> t1 = Task.FromResult(1);
        Task<int> t2 = Task.FromResult(2);
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
        var uuu = t1.Result; 
        // or var uuu = await t1;
```

`

The problem is that visual studio set a `VSTHRD103 Call async methods when in an async method` warning.

I checked with [`sharplab`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugKwDcOA9AFQ4DKAFgIYBOADgDJMBGBwA9vwgBnAmAB2BAEoBXSQFt+MAKYgcgIgICANyYQZygHQBJccLbKAxsAAUASg0ETZy8AMAJZUzbX+3AFYu9tiaTuZWBnTATBYA1tY6espBmmgkCfroUNq6+qhZgGQEQdSUOGgAzAQA3jgEtUQVxABsRAAcRM0AskwSdlU1dQP9A7XIjQA8EsAAfHzoBAC87QYAYiz88lLKwjIQNui2FNjDdaMT4tN8qAtLq+ub27vWqAdDw68DyACcSwDqDMriACCEAg1mAmWAz0Ox1q7zqOhYBBkyOuX1m0JhcNqlEoCIIAC9CajvpCMccsUR0J9rAAiQA8G4AQfZpLyOdQAvjg2UA=) and .Result version jit is a bit smaller.

Can I get any deadlock if I call `.Result` after that I already await them with `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: You should never use Task.Result. It is bad practice.

Comment: @NolanBradshaw except in cases like this, when the tasks are *already* finished

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, missed the await on Task.WhenAll(). Thank you for correcting.

Comment: Related: [Await on a completed task same as task.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result) You may also find this interesting: [Is Task.Result the same as .GetAwaiter.GetResult()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem, as the tasks have *already* finished. This is a false positive which can be ignored.

If all tasks return the same result though, [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___) returns an array with the results:

```
var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The results are in the same order as the tasks that produced them

Comment: You seems to be right but I want to be sure 100% percent

Comment: I agree with this answer-- it's perfectly okay to use `.Result` after the task has been awaited. The only thing I would add is that it is also okay to `await` it again, which would give you the same result, and might be safer.

Comment: As duplicate shows there is indeed differences in cases explicitly not covered in this answer- when Result doesn’t produce result. @ygalbel make sure to check duplicate too

Comment: `await` isn't free.  [Check the issue raised about the analyzer warning](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/issues/541) , you'll see that the extra awaits can increase the application size due to the state machine code : `I also work on the Cortana UWP app and adding four extra await's adds 10-20KB to the app size which is to be avoided. It also hits performance a little.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are wrong, if you read the whole thread you linked, it is concluded that he made a mistake when analyzing app size - and they agreed that an extra await is indeed the best way.