# Running async methods in parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've got an async method, `GetExpensiveThing()`, which performs some expensive I/O work. This is how I am using it:

```
// Serial execution
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetThings()
{
    var first = await GetExpensiveThing();
    var second = await GetExpensiveThing();
    return new List<Thing>() { first, second };
}
```

But since it's an expensive method, I want to execute these calls in in parallel. I would have thought moving the awaits would have solved this:

```
// Serial execution
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetThings()
{
    var first = GetExpensiveThing();
    var second = GetExpensiveThing();
    return new List<Thing>() { await first, await second };
}
```

That didn't work, so I wrapped them in some tasks and this works:

```
// Parallel execution
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetThings()
{
    var first = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return GetExpensiveThing();
    });

    var second = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return GetExpensiveThing();
    });

    return new List<Thing>() { first.Result, second.Result };
}
```

I even tried playing around with awaits and async in and around the tasks, but it got really confusing and I had no luck.

**Is there a better to run async methods in parallel, or are tasks a good approach?**

Comment: @bside You're misrepresenting and the linked post. It correctly states that continuations in `async` functions are scheduled on the captured context. But in most cases that context is the default `SynchronizationContext`, which schedules continuations onto the thread pool, causing them to run in parallel. And even in WPF and ASP apps you can work around it with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. `Task.Run` is used with CPU bound tasks and you don't need it to run continuations in parallel.

Comment: @V0ldek Yes, you are right. Thank you for drawing my attention to this.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Is there a better to run async methods in parallel, or are tasks a good approach?

Yes, the "best" approach is to utilize the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) method. However, your second approach should have ran in parallel. I have created a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ohlscf), this should help shed some light. Your second approach should actually be running in parallel. My fiddle proves this!

*Consider the following:*

```
public Task<Thing[]> GetThingsAsync()
{
    var first = GetExpensiveThingAsync();
    var second = GetExpensiveThingAsync();

    return Task.WhenAll(first, second);
}
```

**Note**

It is preferred to use the "Async" suffix, instead of `GetThings` and `GetExpensiveThing` - we should have `GetThingsAsync` and `GetExpensiveThingAsync` respectively - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24627122/2410379).

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll` will return `Thing[]`, so there's no need for `Result` (in fact, `Result` will wrap exceptions; you should use `await` or use the result of `await Task.WhenAll`).

Comment: Nice catch, thank you - it is early and I've been "awaiting" my coffee. :)

Comment: Whilst this is the generally correct way, what is this doing that `return new List<Thing>() { await first, await second };` is not? If OP said that didn't work, there must be something else at play...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. These methods are still executing sequentially. I can only seem to achieve what I want using those tasks. Would the inner implementation of GetExpensiveThing(), an async method itself, have any effect on this?

Comment: @davenewza what does the implementation of `GetExpensiveThing` look like?

Comment: Quite right. GetExpensiveThing() had an operation which wasn't awaited. The second approach work now.

Comment: Based on this answer, I use `var tasks = new Task[] { GetExpensiveThingAsync(), GetAnotherExpensiveThingAsync(), }; await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: If it's a CPU bound expensive, don't use async. But instead, `Task.Run`

Answer (score 38):

`Task.WhenAll()` has a tendency to become unperformant with large scale/amount of tasks firing simultaneously - without moderation/throttling.

If you are doing a lot of tasks in a list and wanting to await the final outcome, then I propose using a `partition` with a limit on the degree of parallelism.

I have modified [Stephen Toub's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) elegant approach to modern LINQ:

```
public static Task ParallelForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> funcBody, int maxDoP = 4)
{
    async Task AwaitPartition(IEnumerator<T> partition)
    {
        using (partition)
        {
            while (partition.MoveNext())
            {
                 await Task.Yield(); // prevents a sync/hot thread hangup
                 await funcBody(partition.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(
        Partitioner
            .Create(source)
            .GetPartitions(maxDoP)
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(p => AwaitPartition(p)));
}
```

How it works is simple, take an IEnumerable - dissect it into evenish partitions and the fire a function/method against each element, in each partition, at the same time. No more than one element in each partition at anyone time, but n Tasks in n partitions.

Extension Usage:

`await myList.ParallelForEachAsync(myFunc, Environment.ProcessorCount);`

Edit:
I now keep some overloads in a [repository](https://github.com/houseofcat/Tesseract/blob/master/src/HouseofCat.Extensions/IEnumerableExtensions.cs) on Github if you need more options. It's in a NuGet too for NetStandard.

Edit 2: Thanks to comments from Theodor below, I was able to mitigate poorly written Async Tasks from blocking parallelism by using `await Task.Yield();`.

Comment: Nice! This is perfect is you want to use Stephen Toub's approach but prefer to use method-syntax LINQ.

Comment: I am glad you like it, that's exactly what I was going for :)

Comment: The `AsParallel` is redundant. The `Select` that follows is doing no CPU-intensive work. Also by removing the `Task.Run` from Stephen Toub's code you risk a reduced degree of parallelism in case the method `funcBody` is CPU-intensive and completes synchronously.

Comment: AsParallel takes care of Task.Run and Select combined @TheodorZoulias

Comment: @DanHunex replacing the `Task.Run` with `AsParallel` introduces artificial limits to the degree of parallelism, because the configuration `WithDegreeOfParallelism` is missing, so the default `Environment.ProcessorCount` is used. Take a look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J4epIE) fiddle, where the requested `maxDoP: 10` is not respected. Then comment the line `.ParallelForEachAsync_HouseCat` and uncomment the line `//.ParallelForEachAsync_StephenToub`, and see that now the requested DOP is respected.

Comment: I agree with Dan Hunex, but I will re-test the quality of the code implementation.

Comment: Theodor, you are wrong about the parallelism but right about the behavior. The AsParallel() does in fact replace Task.Run(() =>());, but your demonstration showed that a heavy duty synchronous /hot task could invoke execution and hold up the next element. That being said Task.Run(() => will quickly drain from your thread pool and is unnecessary to solve this behavior. I would recommend adding `await Task.Yield();` to my code to prevent these situations. Try it in your fiddle above that very gross Thread.Sleep (which you shouldn't do in async land and use await Task.Delay()).

Comment: @HouseCat by combining `AsParallel`+`Task.Yield` you are close to `Task.Run`, but still the behavior is not identical. The `AsParallel` includes the current thread as one of the worker threads, so if you run your implementation in a UI application with a badly behaving `funcBody`, you'll get a freezed UI. Which is much worse than a saturated thread pool, which will happen anyway with both approaches if the `funcBody` is not implemented asynchronously. With well behaving `funcBody`, no saturation is going to happen with either approach. The `Task.Run` is just simpler and better for this job.

Comment: @HouseCat I should also note that both yours and Stephen Toub's original implementation of `ParallelForEachAsync` are flawed. In case of exceptions, one worker is killed on every exception, and the process continues with a reduced degree of parallelism. If you are unlucky to have exactly `maxDoP - 1` early exceptions, the last standing worker will slowly process all elements alone, until the exceptions are finally surfaced. A less naive implementation should make sure that an exception on any worker will terminate the whole process as fast as possible.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias
Ah yes I agree with your assessments, but if you need fault tolerance and were worried about receiving nefarious types of Exception or Synchronization lock type tasks, I would consider a proper TPL solution. DataflowEngine for example or my Pipelines engine as an idea.

https://github.com/houseofcat/RabbitMQ.Core/blob/master/CookedRabbit.Core/WorkEngines/DataflowEngine.cs

https://github.com/houseofcat/RabbitMQ.Core/blob/master/CookedRabbit.Core/WorkEngines/Pipeline.cs

You really know your stuff! I would love your inputs on these designs if you get a moment ^.^

Comment: I am not very familiar with GitHub. Does it allow having discussions, or simply writing comments related to projects or code-files?

Comment: You can "fork" a copy of anything on Github to your account, edit comments, and submitted them to the main repo if you find issues. Otherwise you can open up "issues" as labelled discussion similar to a forum feature here.

Answer (score 3):

You can your the [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns when all depending tasks are done

Check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747213/is-task-whenall-required-in-the-sample-code) for reference

Answer (score 3):

If `GetExpensiveThing` is *properly* asynchronous (meaning it doesn't do any IO or CPU work synchronously), your second solution of invoking both methods and then awaiting the results should've worked. You could've also used `Task.WhenAll`.

However, if it isn't, you may get better results by posting each task to the thread-pool and using the `Task.WhenAll` combinator, e.g.:

```
public Task<IList<Thing>> GetThings() =>
    Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => GetExpensiveThing()), Task.Run(() => GetExpensiveThing()));
```

(Note I changed the return type to `IList` to avoid `await`s altogether.)

You should avoid using the `Result` property. It causes the caller thread to block and wait for the task to complete, unlike `await` or `Task.WhenAll` which use continuations.