# Concurrent execution of async methods

Tags: c#, async-await

Using the async/await model, I have a method which makes 3 different calls to a web service and then returns the union of the results.

```
var result1 = await myService.GetData(source1);
var result2 = await myService.GetData(source2);
var result3 = await myService.GetData(source3);

allResults = Union(result1, result2, result3);
```

Using typical await, these 3 calls will execute synchronously wrt each other. How would I go about letting them execute concurrently and join the results as they complete?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetData` method?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Stream, string, byte[]...

Comment: Don't await them immediately, store the returned values in an array or list and use `await Task.WhenAll(...);`.

Comment: Yes just found this article that talks a little about WhenAll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @earthling, this is also related: [Why should I prefer single 'await Task.WhenAll' over multiple awaits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How would I go about letting them execute in parallel and join the results as they complete?

The *simplest* approach is just to create all the tasks and then await them:

```
var task1 = myService.GetData(source1);
var task2 = myService.GetData(source2);
var task3 = myService.GetData(source3);

// Now everything's started, we can await them
var result1 = await task1;
var result1 = await task2;
var result1 = await task3;
```

You might also consider [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to consider the possibility that more than one task will fail... with the above code you wouldn't observe the failure of `task3` for example, if `task2` fails - because your async method will propagate the exception from `task2` before you await `task3`.

I'm not suggesting a particular strategy here, because it will depend on your exact scenario. You may only care about success/failure and logging *one* cause of failure, in which case the above code is fine. Otherwise, you could potentially attach continuations to the original tasks to log *all* exceptions, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I Just came across WhenAll. I'll look into using that.  Btw, I assume in the code sample you meant to remove the awaits from the method calls, correct?

Comment: If you `await` `Task.WhenAll` (the common case), it will not throw `AggregateException`. Rather, it will (re)throw *one* of the exceptions from the faulting tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Parallel class:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
() => result1 = myService.GetData(source1),
() => result2 = myService.GetData(source2),
() => result3 = myService.GetData(source3)
);
```

For more information visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This won't help, GetData is an async method, so invoking it in parallel doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a more generic solution you can use the api I wrote below, it also allows you to define a real time throttling mechanism of max number of concurrent async requests.

The inputEnumerable will be the enumerable of your source and asyncProcessor is your async delegate (myservice.GetData in your example).

If the asyncProcessor - myservice.GetData - returns void or just a Task without any type, then you can simply update the api to reflect that. (just replace all Task<> references to Task)

```
    public static async Task<TOut[]> ForEachAsync<TIn, TOut>(
        IEnumerable<TIn> inputEnumerable,
        Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> asyncProcessor,
        int? maxDegreeOfParallelism = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> tasks;

        if (maxDegreeOfParallelism != null)
        {
            SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreeOfParallelism.Value, maxDegreeOfParallelism.Value);

            tasks = inputEnumerable.Select(
                async input =>
                    {
                        await throttler.WaitAsync();
                        try
                        {
                            return await asyncProcessor(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            throttler.Release();
                        }
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            tasks = inputEnumerable.Select(asyncProcessor);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```