# Task.WhenAll in PCL

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, portable-class-library

I'm trying to run a few [async tasks concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117385/parallel-execution-of-async-methods) inside my Portable Class Library, but the [WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method doesn't appear to be supported.

My current workaround is to start each task and then await each of them:

```
var task1 = myService.GetData(source1);
var task2 = myService.GetData(source2);
var task3 = myService.GetData(source3);

// Now everything's started, we can await them
var result1 = await task1;
var result1 = await task2;
var result1 = await task3;
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to make do with the workaround?

Comment: Perhaps you could rewrite it in a way so you can use one of the [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) methods? Those should be supported.

Comment: WhenAll is not supported in Portable Class Libarary, [WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is supported. Can you work around it by waiting on all then starting?

Comment: I can work around it. It's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing?

Yes: [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

Once you install that package, then you can use `TaskEx.WhenAll` as a substitute for `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var task1 = myService.GetData(source1);
var task2 = myService.GetData(source2);
var task3 = myService.GetData(source3);

// Now everything's started, we can await them
var results = await TaskEx.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

P.S. Consider using the term *parallel* for (CPU-bound) parallel processing, and the term *concurrent* for doing more than one thing at a time. In this case, the (I/O-bound) tasks are concurrent but not parallel.

Comment: Cool. I had Microsoft.Bcl.Async installed so TaskEx was just sitting there waiting for me to use it!