# Async methods and race condition

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Async hive mind: 
Consider this

```
private static async Task A()
{
    await DelayOneSecond();
    await DelayOneSecond();
    await DelayOneSecond();
}

private static async Task B()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(DelayOneSecond(), DelayOneSecond(), DelayOneSecond());
}

private static Task DelayOneSecond() => Task.Delay(1000);
```

Which method will complete first? A, B or at the same time?

The code that runs them simultaneously is missing but imagine that bit is there.

My original answer was that await is a not a blocking operation and based on this similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits), these two are similar minus the difference that WhenAll propagates all exceptions at once making it easier not to lose exceptions and also WhenAll will not return immediately if one of the methods throw an exception.

However I was told later that the answer is B, B will complete first because it runs them in parallel. A will run them one after the other waiting for each one to complete before moving on to the next.
I was also told: Await is non-blocking, it hands control back to the caller, the rest of the method is setup as a continuation so went execute until after the awaited call has completed.

I've been trying to find more info about this behaviour because I had assumed multiple awaits would work the same way. Can someone give more explanation on the answer

Comment: Pardon for stating something that maybe stupid, but I don't see how any of them could ever complete, since they don't seem to be called anywhere.

Comment: Right, so the code that runs them in Parallel is missing, but you can imagine that, right?

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: I am planning to, didn't have time to write the task that runs them in parallel yet. This is, for now, a theoretical question

Comment: @xxbbcc I guess that a parallel execution would depend on many factors, and a "trial and conclude" approach is likely to lead to wrong conclusions, or at least not taking into account every cases.

Comment: Just call `A()` and `B()` - why would you need a "task that runs them in parallel"? Put a `Console.WriteLine()` in each call and see what happens.

Comment: @Pac0 No, this is a pretty clear-cut scenario. :)

Comment: If this is a theoretical question, do you want a theoretical answer ;)

Comment: @xxbbcc ow, I see it now. Right. :)

Comment: I have now written a full test in a Console App and B always finishes first. 
I expected that, since I do believe the answer I was given is correct. However the question remains, why? Something so fundamental seems to be missing from so many articles online?

Comment: This is a compiler question, which make change between compiler versions. Presumably the compiler is smart enough to detect no data dependencies and executes the arguments in parallel.

Comment: See the answer in the marked duplicate, with the exception of `WaitAll` (which you did not ask about) this perfectly sums up what you are asking.

Comment: Try it out here: http://rextester.com/XDRXI67199

Comment: @BurnsBA This is not a compiler question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. The question "Does a function evaluate its arguments in order or in parallel?" is authoritatively answered by the compiler, and is explained in the language reference 7.5.1.2. FWIW, arguments are evaluated in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `A` method have 3 sequential `await` statements, the 2nd delay has to wait on the 1st one, and the 3rd has to wait on the 2nd one, it will take *at least* 3 seconds to execute `A()`. (sequential approach)

The `B` method *could* dispatch the `Task`s in different threads, so each one doesn't have to wait on the the others. It will take *at least one second*, and is likely to take much less than 3 seconds.

Comment: But the fact that await is non-blocking means that all 3 should start at the same time?
But it seems that they run synchronously after all

Comment: await does not block the overall application, but having `await` statements sequentially means precisely that they will be executed sequentially, so synchronously. Or maybe I haven't understood how `await` works at all.

Comment: @Nick - `await` is non-blocking in terms of it's a way to declare "the current method cannot make any progress until *this awaitable* is finished - see if my calling code wants to make use of the current thread because I have no use for it"

Comment: You are correct @Pac0. `await` will give back control to the caller. A little bit like how `yield return` works.

Comment: @Nick `await` does not block but does enforce ordering. When you await, your function returns (not blocks) and then resumes when the awaited function completes. `Task.WhenAll()` doesn't specify ordering so those calls may happen in parallel.

Comment: as @Damien_The_Unbeliever wrote, the thread is free to execute other stuff in the meantime - it's usually useful if underlying operation is async I/O, then you can achieve better throughput because your I/O operations are non blocking. Please take a look here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html.

Comment: Okay I am satisfied with the answers. I got await wrong all along! So good to know