# Consume the result of async calls (with different return type) as soon as any one of them is done?

Tags: c#

The following code start `T1Async()`, `T2Async()`, `T3Async()`, `T4Async()` and wait for all of them to finish before consuming the results of these calls. However, the time to run these async calls can be short or very long randomly.

```
Task<int> T1Async() { };
Task<string> T2Async() { };
Task<ClassX> T3Async() { };
Task<ClassY> T4Async() { };

var t1 = T1Async();
var t2 = T2Async();
var t3 = T3Async();
var t4 = T4Async();

var v1 = await t1;
var v2 = await t2;
var v3 = await t3;
var v4 = await t4;
// Or Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t1, t2, t3, t4 });

UseV1(v1); // Want these calls be run asap
UseV2(v2);
UseV3(v3);
UseV4(v4);

UseAll(v1, v2, v3, v4); // Need all the result here
```

How to consume the results as soon as the calling is done and make sure all the results are consumed?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll()` will help you, see this thread as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `Use(...) only needs the result of one call`? This could be the difference between using `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Is it safe to process the results in parallel?

Comment: @ColinM, `Use()` only need one result of any of these async calls.

Comment: @huysentruitw, yes for some intermediate processing. Eventally I need the result of all to do something else.

Comment: So your first thing to do would be to use `Task.WhenAny` to retrieve the first finished task and pass that to `Use`, afterwards, based on what you've said in the comments, use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for the other tasks to finish for `UseAll`

Comment: within each definition of TNAsync(), can't you simply include Use(...) as the final statement?  i.e.,     Task<int> T1Async() { /* do what you were initially planning here, then */  Use(....) };                Do the same for each of your Task definitions, then have a WhenAll()  right before the UseAll(....) at the end.   In that way, the Use() corresponding to each task's result will be able to run as soon as the rest of the task's code is done, and still allow you to wait for them all to complete before moving on UseAll();

Comment: To refer back to @RichardII's question, why can't you handle the `UseVx` method call in the task?

Comment: @huysentruitw, the question you gave doesn't process the result as soon as it completes?

Comment: AFAIK I didn't gave a question. If you're referring to the answer, yes it did process as soon as it completes, in parallel.

Comment: The accepted answer use `await Task.WhenAll(catTask, houseTask, carTask);` which will wait for all the completion of the calls? I want to consume the result if any of them completes.

Comment: Ah you're talking about the duplicate. Yeah it might need tweaking for what you want. Let me do one more effort to answer you question, but don't change the rules this time :)

Comment: If you want to run a task immediately after each completes, why do that asynchronously?  Seems like you can just append that follow-up to each asynchronous task, then await them all to finish for the final job.

Comment: @Nat, in my real situation, depends on some condition, I may need to run, e.g., task 2, 4 before task 1, 3. I cannot simply append these calls in the wrapped async calls.

Comment: I'm not getting precisely what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to implement some more complex logic, then you'll need to write a dispatcher.  Append each async-task with a callback to the dispatcher, then the dispatcher can decide what, if anything, to do after each task completes.

Comment: Yes, a dispatcher should work. Is there any example?

Comment: @ca9163d9 A lot of examples of dispatchers out there, though you'll probably want to ask that as a separate question so you can get an example that's relevant to your use-case.  The accepted answer seems to solve the problem that you were asking about in the above question, so that'd seem to be the way to go if that's all you needed.  If you have a more complex logic to dispatch, then you'll want to be clear about what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to execute the `UseVX` tasks in parallel but await all the results (of different type) in order to pass it to the `UseAll` method.

**Using `Task.Run`**

```cs
var t1 = Task.Run(async () => { var x = await T1(); UseV1(x); return x; });
var t2 = Task.Run(async () => { var x = await T2(); UseV2(x); return x; });
var t3 = Task.Run(async () => { var x = await T3(); UseV3(x); return x; });
var t4 = Task.Run(async () => { var x = await T4(); UseV4(x); return x; });
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
UseAll(t1.Result, t2.Result, t3.Result, t4.Result);
```

**Using `ContinueWith`**

```cs
var t1 = T1().ContinueWith(x => { UseV1(x.Result); return x.Result; });
var t2 = T2().ContinueWith(x => { UseV2(x.Result); return x.Result; });
var t3 = T3().ContinueWith(x => { UseV3(x.Result); return x.Result; });
var t4 = T4().ContinueWith(x => { UseV4(x.Result); return x.Result; });
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
UseAll(t1.Result, t2.Result, t3.Result, t4.Result);
```

Answer (score 2):

To run asynchronous code concurrently, use `Task.WhenAll`. To execute a method as each operation completes, *introduce a new `async` method*:

```
async Task<int> T1AndUseV1Async() { var v1 = await T1Async(); UseV1(v1); return v1; };
async Task<string> T2AndUseV2Async() { var v2 = await T2Async(); UseV2(v2); return v2; };
async Task<ClassX> T3AndUseV3Async() { var v3 = await T3Async(); UseV3(v3); return v3; };
async Task<ClassY> T4AndUseV4Async() { var v4 = await T4Async(); UseV4(v4); return v4; };

var t1 = T1AndUseV1Async();
var t2 = T2AndUseV2Async();
var t3 = T3AndUseV3Async();
var t4 = T4AndUseV4Async();

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);

UseAll(await t1, await t2, await t3, await t4);
```

Comment: It's strange to see code awaiting a Task that was already awaited. Any reason why you'd prefer await here?

Comment: @huysentruitw: Yes; if a future maintainer decides the `await Task.WhenAll` is unnecessary (a matter of opinion) and removes it, then using `await` rather than `Result` will prevent `AggregateException` wrappers.

Comment: Yes, but that's also the job of the maintainer to change `.Result` into `await` in that case. I agree that not every maintainer is aware of this, but the one deciding `Task.WhenAll` is no longer needed, at least should be :)

Comment: @huysentruitw: In theory, yes; in practice, definitely not. Also, in real world code, the `Task.WhenAll` and the `await` are not always so close to each other. Let me turn around the question: it's strange to see `Task.Result` used in asynchronous code. Any reason why you'd prefer `Result` here?

Comment: Because it's the only case in which I actually use .Result. For me, it clarifies the fact that we're sure the Task is done. I'm afraid that by using await in this case, the compiler adds a lot of unwanted bloat.

Comment: There's no runtime impact. The generated code is a little longer for `await`, but I think that's a small price to pay for (slightly) more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

A testable case:

```
async Task<int> T1() { return await Task.FromResult(1); }
async Task<string> T2() { return await Task.FromResult("T2"); }
async Task<char> T3() { await Task.Delay(2000); return await Task.FromResult('A'); }
async Task<string> T4() { return await Task.FromResult("T4"); }

var t1 = T1().ContinueWith(x => { Console.WriteLine($"Use T1: {x.Result}"); return x.Result; });
var t2 = T2().ContinueWith(x => { Console.WriteLine($"Use T2: {x.Result}"); return x.Result; });
var t3 = T3().ContinueWith(x => { Console.WriteLine($"Use T3: {x.Result}"); return x.Result; });
var t4 = T4().ContinueWith(x => { Console.WriteLine($"Use T4: {x.Result}"); return x.Result; });
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```