# Would 'finally' block run once when there are multiple Tasks in the try-catch?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have below C# code that runs periodically, e.g., every 1 hour. Every time it runs, it tries to make some remote calls in parallel. When any of these remote calls throws an exception, I create *only one* ticket, or update the previous ticket. And in the finally block, resolve the existing previous ticket if there is no exception this time. Essentially I want to make sure that no matter how many remote calls fail, I only have one ticket to investigate. And when next time all calls succeed, the ticket gets resolved automatically.

However, when the remote calls all succeed in the try block, the call in finally block tries to resolve the ticket, but ran into HTTP 412 Precondition Failed, meaning that the ticket I got in try block was somehow updated before the finally block. If it's updated in the same thread, I wouldn't try to resolve it.

I learnt from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits) that `Task.WhenAll` will wait for all tasks to complete even in the presence of failures (faulted or canceled tasks). In case where multiple tasks throw exceptions, would the catch block run once or more? How about the finally block?

```cs
Ticket ticket = null;
try
{
    // Query to get the existing ticket if there is any.
    ticket = await QueryExistingTicketAsync();

    // Make a lot of remote calls in parallel
    var myTasks = new List<Task>();
    myTasks.Add(RemoteCallAsync("call1"));
    myTasks.Add(RemoteCallAsync("call2"));
    myTasks.Add(RemoteCallAsync("call3"));
    // ... add more Tasks for RemoteCallAsync()

    await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ticket != null)
    {
        ticket.ReChecked = true;
        ticket.LastCheckTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        // If the previous ticket exists, meaning the last run failed as well, 
        // update the timestamp on that ticket.
        ticket = await UpdateExistingTicketAsync(ticket);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the previous ticket does not exist yet, 
        // create one ticket for investigation, this ticket.ReChecked will be true
        ticket = await CreateNewTicketAsync();
    }
}
finally
{
    // Resolve the previous ticket if it was not created/updated in catch block
    if (ticket != null && !ticket.ReChecked)
    {
        ticket.Status = "Resolved";
        await UpdateExistingTicketAsync(ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: it will only run once, if you want it to run more than once put the try catch finally inside of the logic that gets run async.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the code you posted **there is only one thread**. But you write things like _"multiple threads running in try block"_. That sort of statement doesn't make any sense. Each thread has its own stack, its own exception handling, and thus its own try/catch/finally blocks. If you are unsure of the correct terminology or otherwise cannot explain in English what your question is, please fix the question so it includes a good [mcve], explain _exactly_ what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: I aggree with @PeterDuniho, it's hard to help you the way you stated your question. Are there multiple threads entering this `try` block and then awaiting? Are `myTasks` set up to run in background threads?

As a side-note, I don't know why you want to perform what seems to be business logic when an exception is thrown, but it's a code smell to me.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the guidance, and apologies for the confusion. I was confused by what I saw when I typed the question. I've updated the description and code example, and clarified some details hopefully.

Comment: @V0ldek Added some more details of my intention, I want to be notified when the code failed due to remote call failures, so I create a 'ticket', something like an alert. And I auto-resolve the alert when the next run succeeds, as I don't want to put too much effort on the alert if the error was transient.

Comment: As a minor thing, if you're not doing anything with the `Exception ex` you should omit it. As in 
`try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ... }`

Comment: @V0ldek Thanks. I didn't write out that part, but I do encode the exception info in the ticket for later investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: even if multiple tasks throw exceptions, there will be only one exception thrown by `await Task.WaitAll` and thus the `catch` block will execute only once. The `finally` block always executes once per entry to the `try` block. Long answer follows.

Awaiting a `Task.WaitAll`, if any wrapped `Task`s throw an exception, throws an `AggregateException` containing exceptions from all of the `Task`s. So assuming you've reached the `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` line without exceptions, here's what happens:

1. `Task.WhenAll` will wait for all the `Task`s to complete, regardless of whether they fault or not.
2. If all of the `Task`s completed successfully, the `Task.WhenAll` completes successfully, execution resumes at the `await`, end of the `try` block is reached, the `finally` block executes.
3. If one or more `Task`s finished with an exception, `Task.WhenAll` wraps all of them into an `AggregateException` and completes in a faulted state. The execution resumes at the `await` and the aforementioned `AggregateException` is thrown. The `catch` block is executed and then the `finally` block.

So, assuming that one thread enters the `try` block, in both cases when the execution resumes at the `await` only one thread continues the execution. The only way for you to enter the `catch` or `finally` blocks twice is to execute the method twice.

The `await` statement does a lot of magic under the hood, but it never causes your execution to continue on multiple threads. One thread `await`s, only one thread picks it up and continues.

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` and the `finally` blocks are running once, but can run both. The `finally` block is always running, while the `catch` block runs only in case of an exception, before the `finally` block.

There is another issue with your code though.

```
try
{
    Ticket ticket = await QueryExistingTicketAsync();
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ticket != null)
    {
```

The `ticket` you create on `try` and the `ticket` you update on `catch` is not the same ticket. The `ticket` declared on `try` has local scope, and so it's not visible outside this block. You may have declared another `ticket` variable before the try-catch-finally block, but even in this case the compiler would complain for the double variable declaration. So in any case the code you provided should not be able to compile.

Comment: Thanks, the ticket issue you pointed out was a bug in my sample, I've just fixed it.