# Parallel execution with return values and async/await

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

What is the correct way to handle a part of code that you want to execute at the same time in C#? Each of these calls takes about 3 seconds each (we are making indexing improvements in our systems currently). How do I make these statements execute in parallel with results?

```
var properties = await _propertyService.GetPropertiesAsync("Fairfax, VA");

var ratings = await _ratingsService.GetRatingsAsync(12549);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `await` from invocation and await for result of [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___):

```
var propertiesTask = _propertyService.GetPropertiesAsync("Fairfax, VA");
var ratingsTask = _ratingsService.GetRatingsAsync(12549);
await Task.WhenAll(propertiesTask, ratingsTask);
var properties = propertiesTask.Result;
var ratings =  ratingsTask.Result;
```

Or split method invocation and awaiting (which is usually [less preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits) option):

```
var propertiesTask = _propertyService.GetPropertiesAsync("Fairfax, VA");
var ratingsTask = _ratingsService.GetRatingsAsync(12549);
var properties = await propertiesTask;
var ratings = await ratingsTask;
```

Comment: So does one style have an advantage over the other? I guess the first method is explicit (self-documenting). Any other pros or cons?

Comment: @GuruStron omitting the `await Task.WhenAll` means that if the first task fails, the second task will be leaked as a fire-and-forget task. Which is rarely what you want!

Comment: @BuddyJoe one major difference is exception handling. `Task.WhenAll` will aggregate all exceptions and propagate them to caller while in case of muiltiple `await`'s only the first faulted will be observed.

Comment: @BuddyJoe also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` for that.

`Task.WhenAll` will not block and can be awaited, yielding control back to the caller until all tasks finish (in contrast to `Task.WaitAll`)

In terms of exceptions, If any of the prvided tasks completes in a faulted state, then the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of the unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks.

```
var task1 = _propertyService.GetPropertiesAsync("Fairfax, VA");
var task2 = _ratingsService.GetRatingsAsync(12549);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```