# TaskTupleAwaiter vs Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, async-await

`TaskTupleAwaiter` https://github.com/buvinghausen/TaskTupleAwaiter allows us to do

```
// For example
// Task<int> t1() { return Task.FromResult(1); }
// Task<string> t2() { return Task.FromResult("a"); }
var (r1, r2) = await (t1(), t2());
```

How does it compare to the following code? (Besides more concise code)

```
var t1task = t1();
var t2task = t2();
// var r1 = await t1task; // Edited one is actually I wanted to ask
// var r2 = await t2task;
await Task.WhenAll(t1task, t2task);  
var r1 = t1task.Result;
var r2 = t2task.Result;
```

The project hasn't had any update for a while. I'm wondering if I need to remove it from our repo.

Comment: I'm pretty sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits is what you are looking for...

Comment: The title is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/buvinghausen/TaskTupleAwaiter/blob/master/src/TaskTupleAwaiter/TaskTupleExtensions.cs#L137) `await (t1(), t2())` should be the same as:

```cs
var t1task = t1();
var t2task = t2();
await Task.WhenAll(t1task, t2task);  
var r1 = t1task.Result;
var r2 = t2task.Result;
```

Which should [be preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits) compared to the original code (now commented out) in the question.

> The project hasn't had any update for a while.

The source code was updated only 5 month ago, project targets latest released (at the moment of writing) version of .NET - .NET 6. I would say that for smaller projects which does not have a lot of features such maintainability schedule should be just fine, so personally I see no major reason to switch.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` needs all awaitables return the same type? In the question, `t1` and `t2` can return different types.

Comment: @ca9163d9 no, the code above will compile just just fine if `t1` and `t2` have different return types. `Task.WhenAll()` has overload which accepts just `Task` which is base class for `Task<TResult>`.

Comment: hmm, yes, it works. Interesting, in their page https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskTupleAwaiter, it mentioned that `Enable using the new Value Tuple structure to write elegant code that allows async methods to be fired in parallel despite having different return types`. Just wonder at what case it's not allowed to be fired in parallel when having different return types.

Comment: @ca9163d9 _"Just wonder at what case it's not allowed to be fired in parallel when having different return types."_ - not following you here.

Comment: The nuget page of TaskTupleAwaiter says that it "allows async methods to be fired in parallel despite having different return types". I'm wondering why they said this. It seems async methods can always be fired in parallel despite having different return types?

Comment: Yes ofc, return types hardly play any role in how the method executes.

Comment: @ca9163d9 the nuget states that this _elegant_ structure allows firing in parallel despite having different return types. I would argue that the emphasis is on "elegant", not that it is impossible to fire tasks in parallel despite them having different return types.