# Task.Delay not running

Tags: c#

```
private static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        await MyMethodAsync();
    }

    private static async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        const int count = 10;
        Task<string> loopATask = Task.Run(() => LoopA(count));
        Task<string> loopBTask = Task.Run(() => LoopB(count));
        string resultA = await loopATask;
        string resultB = await loopBTask;
        Console.WriteLine(resultA + resultB);
    }


    public static string LoopA(int count)
    {
        Task.Delay(2000);
        return "LoopA has finished ";
    }

    public static string LoopB(int count)
    {
        Task.Delay(1000);
        return "LoopB has finished ";
    }
```

Expected Output : 2 second delay before writing resultA + resultB

Actual Output:  resulA + resultB is printed instantly

Comment: You're not awaiting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-6.0) is an async operation which should be awaited:

> Creates a task that will complete after a time delay.

So if you don't await it's basically fire and forget operation with an unobserved result.

Change corresponding methods to:

```
public static async Task<string> LoopA(int count)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "LoopA has finished ";
}

public static Task<string> LoopB(int count)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "LoopB has finished ";
}
```

And now you can also scrap `Task.Run` as not needed:

```
Task<string> loopATask = LoopA(count);
Task<string> loopBTask = LoopB(count);
```

Also note that [there are advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits) in using `Task.WhenAll` over multiple sequential `await`'s.