# What is the significance of using Task.WhenAll in C#

Tags: c#

For example, the following code can run normally even if Task.WhenAll is removed. What is the significance of using Task.WhenAll?

```
var getHeadlines = this.RenderViewComponentToStringAsync(typeof(Headline));
var aggTopPosts = this.RenderViewComponentToStringAsync(typeof(AggTopPosts));

await Task.WhenAll(getHeadlines, aggTopPosts);

var result = new
{
    Headlines = await getHeadlines,
    AggTopPosts = await aggTopPosts
};
```

What is the significance of using Task.WhenAll

Comment: I think your use of the word "normally" here is open for interpretation. The code will *run*, no doubt, but it will *behave differently*. In the case *with* the `await Task.WhenAll`, the remainder of the code (`var result = ...`) will only execute **after both** of the two async tasks at the top have completed. If you remove the call to `await Task.WhenAll`, the remainder of the code might execute *while* those tasks are still pending, and then await them as part of the execution. Whether it makes a difference or not is impossible to say from your code fragment, but probably not.

Comment: In addition to my other comment, personally I would've removed the call to Task.WhenAll in this particular code. The double awaiting here (task.whenall + the individual awaits to get the results of those tasks) seems redundant to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I prefer single 'await Task.WhenAll' over multiple awaits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's not redundant. If `getHeadlines` throws, then `aggTopPosts` wouldn't be awaited.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Agreed, I suspect it won't make much of a difference in this case though, but you're right, there *are* behavioral differences here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant difference in this example is if both tasks fails or are canceled.

```
await Task.WhenAll(getHeadlines, aggTopPosts);
```

Will fail with an aggregate exception that contains the exceptions from both tasks. And only do so when both tasks have completed, i.e. either have a result, have failed, or have been canceled.

```
var result = new
{
    Headlines = await getHeadlines,
    AggTopPosts = await aggTopPosts
};
```

If you remove the `WhenAll` and both tasks fail, the exception from `aggTopPosts` will be lost.

It will also throw immediately when `getHeadlines` fails, without awaiting `aggTopPosts`. So if `aggTopPosts` have any observable side effects your program will have different behavior if you include `WhenAll` or not. But if `aggTopPosts` is 'Pure' this should not cause any problems.

Comment: It's more than that. If `getHeadlines` throws, then `aggTopPosts` would not be awaited without the `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay good point, added a paragraph about that.