# Async/await misunderstanding different variant of call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

To understand asynchronous programming in `C#`  I made the following functions:

```
async Task Do()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Do Start 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Do Start 2\n");
  await Task.Delay(3500);
  Console.WriteLine("Do 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Do 2\n");
}

async Task Foo()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Foo Start 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Foo Start 2\n");
  await Task.Delay(1500);
  Console.WriteLine("Foo 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Foo 2\n");
}

async Task Bar()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Bar Start 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Bar Start 2\n");
  await Task.Delay(2500);
  Console.WriteLine("Bar 1");
  Console.WriteLine("Bar 2\n");
}
```

These two variants of function calls work the same:

```
// I variant
Do();
Foo();
Bar();

// II variant
var one = Do();
var two = Foo();
var three = Bar();

// main thread
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
  await Task.Delay(900);
  Console.WriteLine($"Main({i})");
}

Console.ReadLine();
// Output:
//   Do Start 1
//   Do Start 2    

//   Foo Start 1
//   Foo Start 2    

//   Bar Start 1
//   Bar Start 2    

//   Main(1)
//   Foo 1
//   Foo 2    

//   Main(2)
//   Bar 1
//   Bar 2    

//   Main(3)
//   Do 1
//   Do 2
```

First question: these two variants work the same but the `Visual Studio IDE` warns about the first variant that it needs to be changed: `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call`. Why only first variant and not second? Output is good, main thread is not blocked. Why I can't call an `async` function without an `await` keyword?

III variant. Main thread is blocked. I understand if I call these functions in the body of other function but in this situation, when I call them in the Main thread (Program.cs), tell me please what advantages it has with the I and II variants?

```
// III variant
var one = Do();
var two = Foo();
var three = Bar();

// a
await one;
await two;
await three;

// b. the same
// await Task.WhenAll(one, two, three);

// main thread
// for() ...

// Output:
//   Do Start 1
//   Do Start 2    

//   Foo Start 1
//   Foo Start 2    

//   Bar Start 1
//   Bar Start 2    

//   Foo 1
//   Foo 2    

//   Bar 1
//   Bar 2    

//   Do 1
//   Do 2    

//   Main(1)
//   Main(2)
//   Main(3)
```

IV variant. code works synchronously. I understand that it is needed in some situations but I be glad if you tell me more about use cases of it:

```
// IV variant
await Do();
await Foo();
await Bar();

// main thread
// for() ...

// Output:
//   Do Start 1
//   Do Start 2

//   Do 1
//   Do 2

//   Foo Start 1
//   Foo Start 2

//   Foo 1
//   Foo 2

//   Bar Start 1
//   Bar Start 2

//   Bar 1
//   Bar 2

//   Main(1)
//   Main(2)
//   Main(3)
```

Comment: _"IV variant. code works synchronously"_ - You are mixing up "synchronously" and "sequentially". Not sure if an answer can clear up all of the misconceptions apparent in this question.

Comment: Fire and forget on a task issues a warning because it's almost certainly a bug. When you store the task in a variable the language service considers that you might await it later or pass it along or what not.

Comment: @Fildor can you please explain it more deeply?

Comment: In your "II Variant", remove the for-loop and the Console.ReadLine, leaving just the three calls that are not awaited. As (I assume) the console app exits immediately, some messages will be lost. Maybe you need to start the exe from a terminal or command prompt to see the messages

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

Comment: There are too many questions in this post. You could consider focusing one one question only, but be aware that your individual questions have been asked many times before, and duplicate questions exist on this site. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310996/why-should-i-prefer-single-await-task-whenall-over-multiple-awaits "Why should I prefer single 'await Task.WhenAll' over multiple awaits?").

Answer (score 3):

The reason why an IDE warns you that you should do

```
await Do();
```

instead of just

```
Do();
```

is because often it is a mistake, that can be very easily made. The mistake is that simple `Do();` will (or may) run in background, the caller won't wait for it to finish (side note: unless it is sync to begin with, yes, an async function can be sync). And that rarely is intentional. It is harder to make such mistake with

```
var result = await Do();
```

versus

```
var result = Do();
```

because presumably you want to use `result` somewhere, right? If you do, then you will quickly realize that without `await` it has wrong type. Or maybe correct, depending on what you are actually doing. Either way typing will prevent you from making a mistake. On the other hand, if you don't use it, then IDE should warn you about unused variable anyway. So it is hard to make a mistake here.

> IV variant. code works synchronously

No, it is not synchronous. It is sequential. A sequence of opeartions

```
async Task Fire()
{
    await A();
    await B();
    await C();
}
```

will run one after another. But it doesn't prevent other code to run in between. In particular these calls:

```
var t1 = Task.Run(Fire);
var t2 = Task.Run(Fire);
var t3 = Task.Run(Fire);
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

will call `Fire()` three times concurrently. But each `Fire()` will call its own calls sequentially.

With this design we can simply create a complex jobs, where some things happen concurrently, while some one after another.

> I understand that it is needed in some situations

You wanted to say "almost all situations". Whatever you program it is always a desirable property for things to happen in concrete, deterministic way. Calls have to be sequential if they depend on each other, but even if they don't it is desirable to make them in a fixed order one by one. It makes debugging, reasoning about the code easier. The only reason we spawn things in parallel is for performance reasons.

**EDIT:** Variant I and II are functionally the same. You don't do anything with the variables, the jit compiler will eliminate them anyway. Variant II doesn't give warning because the compiler thinks "well, you assign the result to variable, so you must know what you are doing". It should warn you about unused variables though. Either way this is static analysis, it doesn't affect runtime. They both are "fire and forget" types of code.

Variant III is: start Do, then start Foo, then start Bar, then wait for all of them.

This is very different from variant IV that does: start Do, wait for Do, start Foo, wait for Foo, start Bar, wait for Bar. Unlike variant III it doesn't allow Do, Foo and Bar to run concurrently.

You can see those differences if you analyze your own output. The differences will be more visible if you print timestamps additionally. Finally, it is not a matter of what is better. It is only a matter of what you are coding, and what you are trying to achieve. Sometimes one way will be preferable, sometimes the other. That being said typically you will want to await stuff as soon as possible. Meaning treat variant IV as default approach. Deal with other variants only if you have a reason to (probably some optimization).